# How do I complete the sentence, "If you don't mind, ____"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I'm trying to learn the sentence structure and I had a few thoughts about the possible structural continuations of the sentence. I'd appreciate it if you could introduce any new possible continuations of the sentence to me.

> If you don't mind, **I'd like you to stay** with us.
>
> If you don't mind, **I'd appreciate it if you stayed** with us.
>
> If you don't mind, **I'd appreciate you staying** with us.

I'm not sure if such sentence would be grammatically correct, but is it at all possible to have any phrase other than "I would" or in more general terms "(a pronoun) would" after the word "mind," while maintaining the starting phrase of the sentence?

(I'm always looking to improve on my English; so, I'd greatly appreciate it if you would point out any grammatical mistakes I've made in describing my question)

Comment: All three are acceptable colloquial English, though some might state the last as `If you don't mind, I'd appreciate your staying with us.`

Answer (score 1):

As @drmoishe-pippik notes in the comment, all sound correct in US English except that "appreciate you staying" should be "appreciate your staying". All three forms are polite and non-assertive: "If you don't mind, I would..."

More assertive forms would also sound (almost) correct: "If you don't mind, I want you to..." or "...I need you to...". However, in this case I would reverse the phrases:

- I want you to stay with us -- if you don't mind.
- I need you to stay with us -- if you are willing.
- Please stay with us.

In all cases "I" am expressing a desire (that you stay with us) and making it clear that it is "your" decision as to whether to do so.

Comment: Mercifully "I need you to" has not yet caught on in the UK.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian What does "caught on" mean?

Comment: @WXJ96163 To catch on means to become popular. There are examples if its use [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/catch_on). The expression "I need you to" has not yet become popular here.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you, that's very kind of you. "Mercifully" usually means "fortunately", does that indicate that "I need you to" has not yet become popular in the UK is fortunate?

Comment: @WXJ96163 You're  welcome! Yes, that's what I meant. The verb *to need* is defined by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/need) as **Require (something) because it is essential or very important rather than just desirable**. "I need you to..." is therefore much stronger than "I'd like you to..." or "Please would/could you...", all of which we use before "...wash your face", "...pass me the salt" etc. We may need a doctor, we may need help, we may need water... but in the UK, "I need you to wash your face" feels somehow self-centred.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: the acceptability of "need you to" depends on the circumstances, A genuine need is OK, emotional blackmail is not. See my answer.

Comment: @JavaLatte As I said in my comment, it depends on where you live! "I need you to" is not yet popular in the UK. In your examples, only the one that **doesn't** use "I need you to" ("I need to stop off at the laundry") is commonly heard here. It was discussed here: (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/215614/is-i-want-you-to-more-offensive-than-i-need-you-to)

Answer (score 0):

> I would...

Precedes a general request- you could be asking somebody to participate, or you could be offering something, as in

> If you don't mind, I would like to help you with the seating plan

You can use **need** if you are talking about participation in something that would be impossible without the other person's  participation or cooperation.

> If you don't mind, I need you to help me with the seating plan -*maybe not*
>   If you don't mind, I need you to translate for me -*OK*
>   If you don't mind, I need to stop off at the laundry to pick up my dry cleaning -*OK*

The first sentence is grammatically correct, but surely you should be able to do the seating plan on your own- you are just using the word **need** to guilt-trip somebody into helping. The second sentence is fine, because you literally need somebody's help to translate- you could not complete something without the other person's participation. The third sentence is OK if you are travelling together and you need the other person's cooperation in accepting a stop at the laundry.

You can also offer help or ask for cooperationn using **could**

> If you don't mind, I could help with the seating plan
>   If you don't mind, we could share a car to the airport