# "I'm trying to learn" vs. "I'm learning"

Tags: word-usage

An ELL post ([How do I complete the sentence, "If you don't mind, ____"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/214080/109190)) says

> **I'm trying to learn** the sentence structure and I had a few thoughts about the possible structural continuations of the sentence.

I am aware that "I'm trying to learn" is different to "I'm learning".

However, I cannot see the difference of them in the quoted sentence, could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically they mean the same thing.

However, "I'm trying to learn" sounds less forceful than "I'm learning."

"I'm trying to learn" may imply less effort or imply your learning is just a hobby.

"I'm learning" may imply a more strict learning schedule or you are learning in a formal class.